# shiny- Adjust dataTableOutput to size of window

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to get the output table to automatically change size with the size of the window. Currently, the table will adjust the column width to the window, so the columns become wider. I would like it to adjust so the font size increases and decreases to fit the window. Something similar to this http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html.

Here's some simple code:

```
ui <-  function() { 
  fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(matrix(1:25, ncol = 5))})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```